# How does one heal a creature that is petrified & made of stone?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, healing

Whilst in a *petrified condition* (i.e. 'turned to stone') how does such a creature heal? In 5e D&D this condition on creatures presents as 'target is incapacitated + stone-flavoured' (*PhB* 'Conditions' / p.291).

**How can damage to a petrified creature be healed?**

Possible solutions mentioned by other DMs:

1. This creature qualifies as 'incapacitated', thus it can heal as any other creature. Fed potions by allies (?), First Aid bandages or even a good night's rest.
2. Petrified beings are obviously stone statues. A *Mending* spell (PhB, p. 259) will re-affix any damage to any construct (such as: broken finger, arm or even neck), so long as this is less than a square foot of surface area. Heals of any sort *would not work* because this thing cannot bleed, respirate or otherwise benefit from life-enhancing supports (magical or otherwise). Example: a badly injured / dying warrior is medically scratched by a *Cockatrice* (MM p.42) claw. Then the medic uses *Stone Shape* (PhB p.278) to fix all wounds and re-attach all parts - possibly even adding some muscles before the magic ends in 24 hours.
3. This is a form of *suspended animation* and not subject to healing tomfoolery. If brought to zero hit points [the stone creature suffers organ shock and bleeds out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132214/what-happens-if-a-petrified-creature-drops-to-0-hit-points) as pre-established by RAW.
4. This is a role-playing fantasy game - work with the narrative. Logically, wounds *before* becoming a statue are healed with *magical* aid. Damage done *after* petrification is repaired *magically* as pottery or other stonewares. Non-magical means (Band-Aid®, Crazy Glue® or otherwise) simply do NOT work.

**Are there any official rules (in books, including VGM or XGtE or Crawford's tweets) clarifying this matter?**

Comment: Possibly related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137088/can-mending-be-used-to-reattach-severed-body-parts

Comment: What makes you say "Heals of any sort would not work because this thing cannot bleed, respirate or otherwise benefit from life-enhancing supports"? This sounds like a logical approach, but logic doesn't dictate the rules. Nothing says a heal would fail to work on statue-esque petrified characters because they don't bleed or respirate.

Comment: @ David Coffin - This is a question with various suggestions from various DMs. I am sorry if their ideas upset you. If you have an answer, please let us know!

Comment: @Jason_c_o I did a very similar format and style of question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136153/what-spell-list-must-dragons-use-if-any) and it worked out quite well. Perhaps the true limit is not the website, but the [culture](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2018/03/17/stack-overflow-culture/) that has been developed here.

Comment: @TimofTime Also, the comments aren't the best place to discuss the culture of the site. If you have a specific concern please bring it to Meta or Chat :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "petrified" condition applies several modifiers to a creature:

- its weight increases by a factor of ten
- it ceases aging
- it is incapacitated, meaning it cannot take actions
- it can't move or speak
- it is unaware of its surroundings
- attack rolls against it have advantage
- it automatically fails strength and dexterity saving throws
- it has resistance to all damage
- it is immune to poison and disease

Nothing on that list says the creature can't be healed normally.

In D&D 5e, [rules only do what they say, and no more than that](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret).  (The link points to discussion of a Crawford tweet, as requested.)

Rules As Written, that means that *cure wounds* will work on a petrified creature and *mending* will not work.

If the DM thinks the Rules As Written are not realistic in a given situation, the DM has the ability to add additional rules or to interpret existing rules in whatever way they want.  But we can't tell you how your DM should do that.